# Xamarin.Forms - WPF inputbinding alternative?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get to know Xamarin for app building. I'm trying to build a Win8 app, and I want to have some events that are triggered by keystrokes on the physical keyboard. In WPF you can do this by:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding UpCommand}" Key="Up"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding DownCommand}" Key="Down"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding LeftCommand}" Key="Left"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding RightCommand}" Key="Right"/>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Pause}" Key="Space"/>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

What's the alternative to this in a Xamarin page? Thank you!

Comment: This might sound like nitpicking, but _Xamarin_ has nothing to do with Windows 8 apps. It's all about bringing C# to iOS, Android and macOS. What you likely mean is _Xamarin.Forms_ which is a cross platform framework that abstracts the UI layer for iOS, Android and the Windows platforms. If you want to create a pure Win8 app, there is no need to abstract anything, Microsoft has all you need. You might want to update your question: is it about X.Forms, or is it a question about a native Windows app?

Comment: This is nitpicking. Xamarin is for cross-platform development, which includes apps for Windows, iOS and Android (and Universal Windows Applications and Windows Phone applications). The question is about an application made with Xamarin targeted at a Win8 app.

Comment: I repeat what I already wrote: you *cannot* make an app for Windows 8 with Xamarin. If you'd like to get answers please make clear what you are asking. If it is about Forms, you should tag it as such.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/tablet/ Read this, then.

Comment: Yep...thanks for confirming what I said... ;-) See how the URL contains "xamarin_-forms_"?

Comment: Dude you're honestly just trying to flip me off. I'm using Xamarin to build an app that will run on Windows 8. What is there not to understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to make a complete answer out of what I learned from the comments. Please understand that there really is a difference between Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms, just like there is a difference between an apple and a pear, although both are tasty fruit.

Xamarin offers you two ways of writing apps:

- The traditional approach
- or using Xamarin.Forms

In the traditional approach you use C# (or F#) to bring your code to iOS, Android or Mac. This is possible because of [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com). You will have to know the platform specific APIs of all targeted platforms. You write your UI relevant parts for each platform and reuse your business logic. If you want to target Windows platforms, there is no need for anything Xamarin specific.

Then there is [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms): a framework provided by Xamarin that allows you to abstract the UI layer and work with models of the UI and under the hood it translates everything into platform specific features. You don't have to deal with platform specific APIs anymore. It is also using Mono to target iOS and Android. However, it is using Microsoft .NET to target Windows Phone, Windows 8 and UWP.

Why is this difference important? Because it shows us that there are two ways to make an app cross platform compatible. Your question was about Win8 and to give the correct answer it matters what technology you are using. You are asking for a feature that does not exists because Xamarin has nothing to do with Win8. So one possible answer is: you don't have to use Xamarin, you simply use the tools Microsoft provides to you.

Interpreting the comments above, I now understand that you want to use Xamarin.Forms and you ask what the XAML counterpart of `KeyBinding` is. There is no support for this in Forms out of the box. The idea of Forms is to abstract the UI across all possible platforms. iOS does not have a keyboard, most Android devices don't have it either. This means that in your case you will have to make use of the platform specific projects that are used by Forms. One of these will be a Win8 project where you can use exactly the code you originally posted. You will then have to forward the commands into your shared code for further processing.

Comment: Thank you for this! Much appreciated. I currently have a portable project for the abstraction of what is not platform-specific, and then I have a UWP project in which I want to implement the UWP specific stuff (like controls and the view). However, this code does NOT work (produces the error `Error: The attachable property 'InputBindings' was not found in type 'Window'. App1.UWP`) in the UWP targeted project, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @lte__ I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution for it yet?

Comment: @ShwetaGoyal Phew I probably did, but this was 2 and a half years ago and I don't remember + haven't touched WPF since... Sorry!